# Uncaught exception thrown by filter springSecurityFilterChain on web sphere Application server

Tags: spring-boot, websphere

I am getting the following error during the server startup

filter        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper doFilter SRVE8109W: Uncaught exception thrown by filter springSecurityFilterChain: 
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.sessionCreated(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent;)V
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.managedobject.ManagedObjectListenerWrapper.sessionCreated(ManagedObjectListenerWrapper.java:82)

0000012d SystemOut     O 2020-01-11 20:57:13.371 ERROR 15596 --- [ebContainer : 0] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/helloWorldPage] due to exception [java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.sessionCreated(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent;)V]

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.sessionCreated(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent;)V

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what Version of the Servlet API you're using and what version of WebSphere it is hard to say for sure if this is the issue but my initial suspicion is that you're running on a Servlet Version that is earlier than Servlet 4.0.

In Servlet 4.0 there are default methods on the [HttpSessionListener](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) interface. If you look at Servlet 3.1 there is no default implementation on the [HttpSessionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html).

You should verify which version of the Servlet Specification is required for the Application.